# Is there a way to only use GPU for headless chrome process instead of CPU?

Tags: google-chrome, kubernetes, nvidia, nvidia-docker

google-chrome --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 
--no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --disable-infobars 
--window-size=$window_size_x,$window_size_y --window-position=0,0 --disable-dev-shm-usage --no-sandbox 
--no-sandbox-and-elevated 
--no-zygote 
--enable-webgl 
--use-gl=desktop 
--use-skia-renderer 
--enable-gpu-rasterization 
--enable-logging=stderr 
--kiosk wwww.google.com

**Details:**
Tried removing --disable-gpu flag in headless chrome

1. In my scenario, I want to shift all load to GPU as it's free and other things
   require a GPU based machine and these types of machines have fewer
   CPU cores which means we can not run more Kubernetes pods on a
   single machine because of a CPU bottleneck
2. OS: Ubuntu
3. Using Kubernetes pod which is ubuntu based pod.  Using Nvidia based
   machine in the AWS environment.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @NikhilShinday Still no solution even discussed with the NVIDIA team, they also did not have a solution. But I eventually optimized by disabling a lot of things like using skia-renderer, disabling extensions and a lot more. You can read more when you enable only the things which are only required for your use case.